# vue.js breaking svg-animate

Tags: vue.js, svg, svg-animate

As soon as i use `new Vue(...)` the svg animation does not work.

I was not able to find others having the same issue ... though most animate directly with Vue.js

I tried it with anime.js, but it also does not work together with vue.js. Does anyone know a solution to this?

without Vue.js

```js
toBars = document.getElementById("toBars");
toCross = document.getElementById("toCross");

isBars = true;
document.getElementById("start").onclick = function () {
    (isBars ? toCross : toBars).beginElement();
    isBars = !isBars;
};

//new Vue({ el: "#app" });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

    <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="128">
        <path id="p" d="M3 6 L29 6" stroke="black" stroke-width="6">
            <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="d" from="M3 6 L29 6" to="M3 3L29 29" dur="0.2s" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" id="toCross" />
            <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="d" from="M3 3L29 29" to="M3 6 L29 6" dur="0.2s" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" id="toBars" />
        </path>
    </svg>

    <button id="start">Click to start</button>

</div>
```

With Vue.js

```js
toBars = document.getElementById("toBars");
toCross = document.getElementById("toCross");

isBars = true;
document.getElementById("start").onclick = function () {
    (isBars ? toCross : toBars).beginElement();
    isBars = !isBars;
};

new Vue({ el: "#app" });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

    <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="128">
        <path id="p" d="M3 6 L29 6" stroke="black" stroke-width="6">
            <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="d" from="M3 6 L29 6" to="M3 3L29 29" dur="0.2s" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" id="toCross" />
            <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="d" from="M3 3L29 29" to="M3 6 L29 6" dur="0.2s" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" id="toBars" />
        </path>
    </svg>

    <button id="start">Click to start</button>

</div>
```

Comment: After Vue mount to `#app` they create a new entire DOM so the `svg` you see and the `svg` that your variables hold is difference. You should move your code to mounted call back instead.

Answer (score 0):

As User 28 pointed out, it all has to be in the context of Vue.js

(I tried this before, but must have had another error.)

Working example:

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    template: `
<div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="128">
        <path id="p" d="M3 6 L29 6" stroke="black" stroke-width="6">
            <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="d" from="M3 6 L29 6" to="M3 3L29 29" dur="0.2s" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" ref="toCross" />
            <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="d" from="M3 3L29 29" to="M3 6 L29 6" dur="0.2s" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" ref="toBars" />
        </path>
    </svg>
    <button v-on:click="toggleState">Click to start</button>
</div>

`,
data: () => { return { isCross: false } },
methods: {
    toggleState: function() {
      console.log(this);
        this.isCross = !this.isCross;
        if (this.isCross)
            this.$refs.toCross.beginElement();
        else
            this.$refs.toBars.beginElement();
    }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

</div>
```